# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory in android

Tags: java, android

I rebuilt my project and got this error. I'm unable to find where it's coming from. The full log is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.validateListFilesParameters(FileUtils.java:545)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.listFiles(FileUtils.java:521)
    at android.databinding.tool.store.ResourceBundle.loadClassInfoFromFolder(ResourceBundle.java:157)
    at android.databinding.tool.store.LayoutInfoInput$deps$2.invoke(LayoutInfoInput.kt:63)
    at android.databinding.tool.store.LayoutInfoInput$deps$2.invoke(LayoutInfoInput.kt:30)
    at kotlin.UnsafeLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:154)
    at android.databinding.tool.store.LayoutInfoInput.getDeps(LayoutInfoInput.kt)
    at android.databinding.tool.store.LayoutInfoInput$existingBindingClasses$2.invoke(LayoutInfoInput.kt:86)
    at android.databinding.tool.store.LayoutInfoInput$existingBindingClasses$2.invoke(LayoutInfoInput.kt:30)
    at kotlin.UnsafeLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:154)
    at android.databinding.tool.store.LayoutInfoInput.getExistingBindingClasses(LayoutInfoInput.kt)
    at android.databinding.tool.BaseDataBinder.<init>(BaseDataBinder.kt:40)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.databinding.DataBindingGenBaseClassesTask$CodeGenerator.run(DataBindingGenBaseClassesTask.kt:203)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.databinding.DataBindingGenBaseClassesTask.writeBaseClasses(DataBindingGenBaseClassesTask.kt:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    ... 33 more
```

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: share your code as well

Comment: Does this error while executing a Gradle task? If so, include your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: It might just be an android thing here, not into it, but the error also happens when you try to get a file from a path that just is not there. You might be on another machine than you think you are. Check the working directory and find out whether the paths to all needed files are right. See [Parameter 'directory' is not a directory for a parameter which is a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75154048/11154841), with other answers as well.

Answer (score 92):

I've had the same problem. All I did was:

1. Delete the *.gradle* directory under the project root files
2. Invalidate Caches and restart Android Studio.

Comment: To clarify, the .gradle directory is under the project instead of the one under user's home directory.

Comment: Very weird, changed branches and saw this for the first time. Thank you for the solution.

Comment: As in case of gentleman above, my build broke after just switching between git branches, and this answer helps.

Comment: The tip for `.gradle` under project dir was helpful, as I thought people meant the home dir `.gradle`, which didn't fix it for me