# Android Hilt - multi module project cast error

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, dagger, dagger-hilt

I am trying to use hilt for my project which contains dynamic features. I am facing an error that I cannot fully understand why. I get an error like this:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.social.analysis.DaggerApp_HiltComponents_ApplicationC$ActivityRetainedCImpl$ActivityCImpl$FragmentCImpl cannot be cast to com.social.login.intro.IntroFragment_GeneratedInjector
    at com.social.login.intro.Hilt_IntroFragment.inject(Hilt_IntroFragment.java:94)
    at com.social.login.intro.Hilt_IntroFragment.initializeComponentContext(Hilt_IntroFragment.java:58)
    at com.social.login.intro.Hilt_IntroFragment.onAttach(Hilt_IntroFragment.java:50)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onAttach(Fragment.java:1602)
    at com.social.login.intro.Hilt_IntroFragment.onAttach(Hilt_IntroFragment.java:40)
```

**My ViewModel in LOGİN MODULE (dynamic features)**

```
class IntroViewModel @Inject constructor(): ViewModel() {
// TODO: Implement the ViewModel
}
```

**My Fragment in LOGIN MODULE**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class IntroFragment : BaseFragment<FragmentIntroBinding, IntroViewModel>(
R.layout.fragment_intro
) {

companion object {
    fun newInstance() = IntroFragment()
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
}

override fun onInitDataBinding() {
    viewBinding.viewModel = viewModel
}
}
```

**My Base Fragment in UI Module**

```
abstract  class BaseFragment <B: ViewDataBinding, M: ViewModel>(
@LayoutRes
private val layoutId: Int
): Fragment() {

@Inject
lateinit var viewModel: M
lateinit var viewBinding: B
...
```

**My Application Class in App Module**

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class App : SplitCompatApplication() {
}
```

**My Main Activity in App Module**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
```

I call the IntroFragment from the App module. Then the application crashes.

The project structure looks like this:

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: You should use dagger2 instead of hilt when using dynamic feature module

Comment: did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: A dagger should be used instead of a dagger-hilt.

Comment: I am having this problem even without dynamic features... I have my activity in a simple "com.android.library". @MuratAKSU the only solution you found was to use dagger2?

Comment: As far as I know, this problem only happens when using the dynamic features module. Something else could be causing the error. @amp

Comment: @MuratAKSU you are totally right. After a clean and rebuild it worked.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? And how

Comment: i am facing similar situation so far no solution

Comment: me too @MohammadMuddasir, app crashes when my dynamic feature fragment is annotated with AndroidEntryPoint

Comment: Hi guys, same problem here when trying to use Hilt, anyone available to help? I tried all the solutions but without success

Any luck?
@kakaranara

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54018148/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-parameter-directory-is-not-a-directory-in/57872793#57872793):

Delete the .gradle directory (in the project base directory)
Invalidate Caches and restart Android Studio.

Comment: I had the same problem and this solved it for me thanks

Comment: Crown this guy!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using dynamic feature module, don't forget to remove @AndroidEntryPoint annotation. Because the annotation is from Hilt and you used the Dagger2 as DI.