# Android studio: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-build

When I try to build my project, I get such a mistake:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug'.
> Parameter 'directory' is not a directory
```

Comment: Please show the full stacktrace

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54018148/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-parameter-directory-is-not-a-directory-in)

Answer (score 42):

From [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57872793/358006):

1. Delete the .gradle directory (in the project base directory)
2. Invalidate Caches and restart Android Studio (if necessary)

EDIT: Step 2 doesn't appear necessary on *nix systems

Comment: Just the first step, i.e. `rm -rf .gradle/` did the trick for me.

Comment: For me was enough first step. `rm -rf .gradle/`

Comment: Worked for me too.  I saved the files before delete and grep'ed for the word directory and none had it.  Weird...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I had to clear data off of my device (emulator), and cold boot, then everything ran.

Wasted a lot of time on this.